# Merge en laravel dentro ForEach

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Un saludo.

Tengo una coleccion que ya funciona en mi laravel.
pero necesito a cada registro de la coleccion agregarle un dato nuevo.
es el resultado de una suma de registros.

pero no logro que mi actual coleccion me retorne igualita, solo que esta vez con un atributo mas.

Esta es mi actual colleccion, del modelo Revisiones. Que me devuelve unos datos, se los paso a la vista y hasta ahora ok.

```
$servicios = Revisiones::where($busqueda)
                    ->join('lectores as le', 'le.id', 'revisiones.operador_id')
                    ->where('envio', '!=', '5')
                    ->where('envio', '!=', '6')
                    ->groupBy('route')
                    ->get();
```

esto me devuelve esto:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1398 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1418 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1415 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Pero por cada registro que me devuelve, yo hago una subconsulta. para calcular una suma, y el resultado quiero agregarselo, pero el resultado no es el esperado.
me cambia totalmente la coleccion, yo intento hacer esto.

```
  $servicios = Revisiones::where($busqueda)
                        ->join('lectores as le', 'le.id', 'revisiones.operador_id')
                        ->where('envio', '!=', '5')
                        ->where('envio', '!=', '6')
                        ->groupBy('route')
                        ->get();

$servicios = collect($servicios);

                  foreach ($servicios as $collection) {

                        $cantidad = Revisiones::where('envio', '!=', '5')
                        ->where('envio', '!=', '6')
                        ->where('operador_id', $collection->operador_id)
                        ->where('fecha_carga', $collection->fecha_carga)
                        ->count();

                        $servicios = collect($collection)->merge(['cantidad' => $cantidad]);

                    }
```

pero entonces, lo que ahora me devuelve es esto:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1403 ▼
  #items: array:44 [▶]
}
```

estos registros que son los que ya funcionan:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1398 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1418 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1415 ▶}
  ]
}
```

cada coleccion, contiene datos asi:

```
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1398 ▼   #items: array:2 [▼
>     0 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1418 ▼
>       #table: "revisiones"
>       +timestamps: false
>       #connection: "mysql"
>       #primaryKey: "id"
>       #keyType: "int"
>       +incrementing: true
>       #with: []
>       #withCount: []
>       #perPage: 15
>       +exists: true
>       +wasRecentlyCreated: false
>       #attributes: array:43 [▼
>         "numero_revision" => 12345678
>         "envio" => 0
>         "numacta" => 2121212
>         "fecha_carga" => "2021-07-15 00:00:00"
>         "ejecutor" => 710
>         "operador_id" => 264
>       ]
```

y despues del merge, en los atributos quiero poder agregar un atributo nuevo, "cantidad" podria ser despues de operador_id, el orden no importa algo asi:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1398 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Revisiones {#1418 ▼
      #table: "revisiones"
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:43 [▼
        "numero_revision" => 12345678
        "envio" => 0
        "numacta" => 2121212
        "fecha_carga" => "2021-07-15 00:00:00"
        "ejecutor" => 710
        "operador_id" => 264
        "cantidad" => 20
      ]
```

y no se como concatenarlo, o como hacer el merge correcto, para agregarle un atributo a cada item del array. alguien podria ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega por favor una muestra de la estructura que esperas que tengan los datos de salida

Comment: gracias, ya hice las modificaciones.